# can any one help me fix this react problem

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

[error am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGwRx.png)

This is the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

This is the App.js where i import ConfigureStore.js file

```
import './App.css';
import Main from './components//MainComponent';
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configurStore'

const store= ConfigureStore()

class  App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
                 
          <Main  />
          
        </div>
      </Provider>

      

    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

This is the reducer.js file which is use in configerstor.js file

```
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes"
import { COMMENTS } from '../shared/comments';
import { PROMOTIONS } from '../shared/promotiones';
import { LEADERS } from '../shared/leaders'

export const initialState = {
    dishes: DISHES,
    comments: COMMENTS,
    promotions: PROMOTIONS,
    leaders: LEADERS
};

export const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return state ;
};
```

This is the  configurstor.js file

```
import createStore from 'redux';
import { Reducer, initialState } from './reducer'

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        Reducer, 
        {},
        initialState
    );

    return store;
}
```

This is the Maincomponent.js file

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        location={location}
        params={params}
        navigate={navigate}
      />
    );
  }}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes,
    comments: state.comments,
    promotions: state.promotions,
    leaders: state.leaders
  }
}
class  Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        
      }

  render(){
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Main));
```

I tried to import  withrouter from react-router-dom but it  shows me this errore

[error when i import withRouter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8u0a.png)

so i write withRouter

Comment: Please include all relevant code and error messages in text, images make your code harder to read/manipulate (as well as harder to search for future users with similar problems)

Comment: Please edit the post to include all relevant code as properly formatted and readable code snippets. Images of text, errors, and code are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you *actually* trying to use here? Can you share your package.json file so we can see the dependencies *and* can you run `npm list react-router-dom` from the project directory to check what version is installed and report back the result?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a few issues with imports and dependencies.

1. You are ***default*** importing Redux and naming it `createStore` instead of importing the ***named*** `createStore` export.

   Instead of `import createStore from 'redux';`

   it should be `import { createStore } from 'redux';`
2. It appears you've installed the latest version of `react-router-dom`, version 6, which does not export any `withRouter` Higher Order Component any more.

   If you intend to continue using the `withRouter` HOC then you need to revert back to RRDv5. In the terminal in the root project directory run the following to install the older version and update your package.json file:

   `npm install --save react-router-dom@5`

   If you intend to continue using RRDv6 then you'll need to address any breaking changes between versions. Remove the `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';` and follow the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) migration guide. You'll want to also read though the [Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts) and [FAQ](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq) to get a good sense of what changed and how to better use RRDv6.